# Sphinx:Server sent charset unknown to the client. Please, report to the developers

Tags: php, mysqli, sphinx

I'm using Sphinx 2.0.5 and while I call indexer through PHP, Im getting error **Sphinx:Server sent charset unknown to the client. Please, report to the developers**. What can be the problem ?

Server PHP version is 5.6.30

**Only problem occurs when trying to connect Sphinx using mysql or mysqli via PHP.**

```
$link = mysqli_connect ( "127.0.0.1", "root", "", "", 9306 ) or sendErrorMail(array("subject"=>"Failed to connect to sphinx ","sql"=>"","error"=> mysqli_connect_error()));
```

OR

```
$link = mysql_connect ( "127.0.0.1:9306", "", "" ) or sendErrorMail(array("subject"=>"Failed to connect to sphinx","sql"=>"","error"=> mysql_error()));
```

Is the a requirement of any configuration changes ? 
What am I missing ? Can anyone help ?

Below code works fine :

```
    $cl = $this->sphinxclient;
    $cl->resetFilters();
    $cl->SetMatchMode(SPH_MATCH_EXTENDED2);
    $cl->setFilter('eventid',array($param['eventId']));
    $result = $cl->Query('','indexerName');
```

In linux Sphinx gets connected properly using below command :

**`mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -P 9306`**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it solved. 
Probably this occurs with PHP version > 5.4. 
In Sphinx Installation Bundle there is a file **"searchd.cpp"**. 
Over there **server language** is specified as **\x00** change it to **\x21** and reinstall sphinx. Problem will be solved.